# Checking file status and deleting it (Linux drive mapped in Windows)

Tags: java, linux, windows, file, delete-file

I have written a small application to archive historical data from a set of weather station. My program does the following:

- Check if input file exists
- Check if input file is open by another program (probably, the application sending data from the weather stations).
- Append all the contents to an archive file.
- Delete the input file (will be created again next time there is new data from the weather stations).

The Java program is running on a Windows machine, and if accessing a local file everything runs smoothly (I can check whether the file exists and whether it is in use). But when we started using a Linux drive mapped onto the Windows machine, I started getting false negatives on the exists-check and false-positives on the in-use-check.

Any ideas on what I can do to make it work?

Here is my code:

```
File originalFile = new File (currentPath +  "\\" + line[1]);
if (originalFile.exists()) { 
    boolean fileIsNotLocked = originalFile.renameTo(originalFile);
    if (fileIsNotLocked) {

        /* WORK WITH THE FILE TO COPY ITS CONTENTS ETC */

        if(originalFile.delete())
            System.out.println("Successfully deleted file at = " + originalFile);
        else
            System.out.println("Could not delete file at = " + originalFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, consider using `File.separator` instead of `"\\"`.

Comment: Is this sporadic behavior, or does it never succeed on the mapped drive? I ask because you mentioned results from the in-use-check, but that would always fail if the `exists()` failed. If that's the case and @Everv0id's File.separator suggestion doesn't work, I'd confirm currentPath is what you expect (different drive letter on the map?).

Comment: Other way is to keep all files used by your code in project directory and use relative paths.

Comment: That would keep this simple but may not make long-term sense with a mapped drive to a machine elsewhere. Also consider inspecting `System.out.println("Absolute path: " + originalFile.getCanonicalPath());`

Comment: The problem was actually very simple, I could not access a File that has been shared via Samba without using the JCIFS library.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the solution was using the JCIFS library: https://jcifs.samba.org/

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the green tick. This marks the problem as solved in StackOverflow.

Comment: If you recommend a library, please show how it can be applied. Add some example code to your answer.